# Creating Auto-Scrolling Gallery with JQuery; Need advice on correct code

Tags: javascript, events, slider, jquery

I'm trying to create an auto-scrolling image gallery from scratch. Right now, I've written the images to change when a hover occurs.

My theory was that I could use '.ready' and create a loop of these functions. I attempted to create it but I still don't know how to recall these functions correctly.

What event(s) would I use to create a looping occurrence of this effect? I'm also looking for critique on my thinking here so I appreciate any insight outside of the plain answer.

Here's the code! Thanks guys!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#blinds_1').show();
$('#blinds_2').hide();

$("#blinds_1").mouseover(function(){
    $('#blinds_1').fadeOut(600);
    $('#blinds_2').slideDown(600);
});

$("#blinds_2").mouseout(function(){
    $('#blinds_1').slideDown(600);
    $('#blinds_2').fadeOut(600);
});

});
```